# Show the user the requirements for a CanCan ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

On Rap Genius you need a certain amount of Rap IQ before you get certain permissions (it's like Stack Overflow in this regard). I've implemented this by adding lines like this to my `ability.rb`:

```
can :create, Annotation do |a|
  user.rap_iq >= 500
end
```

However, I need to be able to communicate this fact to users. E.g., in my annotations view I might have something like:

```
<% unless can? :create, @annotation %>
  You need at least <%= CanCan::Ability.iq_required_to(:create, Annotation) %> Rap IQ to create annotations
<% end %>
```

(obviously the API is made up lol)

My question is how best to do this – I'm sure this problem has been solved before (e.g., in Stack Overflow's case!)

Answer (score 2):

You could model this requirement information in some way and show it to the user.

I don't know if there is already a way to do this with cancan (I've not seen it in documentation yet) but you could extend the `CanCan::Ability` class to respond to `iq_required_to`, something like (it's just a **proof of concept**):

```
REQUIREMENTS[:annotation][:create] = 500

def iq_required_to(action, subject)
  REQUIREMENTS[subject][action]
end
```

and then you can call `iq_required_to(:create, :annotation)`

of course you should change your `initialize` to use this information:

```
can :create, Annotation do |a|
  user.rap_iq >= iq_required_to(:create, :annotation)
end
```

Comment: yeah, this is what i was thinking of doing.. the only problem is there's way to determine WHY a user can't do something. i.e., there might be non-iq related reasons the user can't add an annotation, so if i use this technique, i'm going to have to REMEMBER that there is an IQ requirement both in my ability.rb AND in my views. this is what i'm trying to avoid. any thoughts keeping this DRY?

Comment: Of course this "solution" don't take in account other kind of requirements but it could be OK if your application has a system like SO as you said since it's the main way to determine what a user can do. Consired for other kind of authorization constrains you can't show this message (if to do something you need to be an administrator for example let the user know this doesn't change the fact he is not an administrator), I don't know if I'm clear, if have a reputation greater than a certain amount is sufficient to do something this *could* be OK.

Comment: I've read a bit of CanCan code and the `CanCan:Ability` module (you include in the `ability.rb` model) has some interesting variables and methods that CanCan use to check what a user can do or not. I'm talking about `@rules` (an array of `CanCan::Rule` instances) and the `relevant_rules_for_query(action, subject)` method (an array of `CanCan::Rule`s). These are both private but you could wrap in a public method, say `why_cannot(action, subject)` but you should process the rules to determine the cause (`CanCan::Rule` have a `@conditions` hash)...advanced (at least for me), but *maybe* viable